# Adding Controls using Javascript and get Their Value from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, controls

I wanna add server controls by using javascript. The main purpose of why I want is to add controls without any postback and get them in code-behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the Request.Form collection for all form values (client side controls) on the server.  Each control will need to have a unique ID to access it in the request.Form collection.

For example, if you had the following control

```
<input type="text" id="testBox" value="blah" />
```

On the server you would access the value as Request.Form["testBox"].

Answer (score 2):

Try to access the html inputs with [Request.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985.aspx)

```
Request.Form["inputName"]
```

You will have to set the `name` attribute on your inputs like this:

```
<input type="text" value="blah" name="inputName" />
```

Comment: Thanks but I guess I can't choose 2 answers as an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

if its a form post you can get the value with request.form["control"] one of the properties will help you do it,
if its a new control in some page you can do something with ajax , i did not try it, its just a theory,

you can make an ajax request that will create a textboox control in the server and then render the html to your page.

now when you will call text1.text you will get the value ..

but its a bit of an hack to me..

Answer (score 0):

That is not generally possible. You must add server side controls *on the server*.

If you want to avoid the *visibility* of a postback, use AJAX and an UpdatePanel. Otherwise you're out of luck.